# How can JQuery validate() be executed before onClick="functionname()";

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, onclick, validation

A form, I use AJAX to transfer the data. The AJAX is triggered by onClick="", I also use JQuery validate(). JQuery validate() is executed after the onclick=“function()", I would like the JQuery validate() is executed before the onclick="functionname()", how to do it?

```
<?php $addtext=<<<html
<a id="give_comment" href="javascript:void(0)">Supplement</a>
<div id="comment_text" name="comment_text" style="display:none">
<form id="add_text" action="nofile.php"  method="post" onsubmit="return false;">
<textarea  id="giver_comment_text" name="giver_comment_text" rows="6" cols="70" class="font1"></textarea><br/>
<input id="giver_submit_comment" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="validateDetail()" /></form></div>
<br/>
html;
echo $addtext;
?>
```

Javascript code:

```
function validateDetail()
{
  $('#add_text').validate({
        rules:{
            giver_comment_text:{
                required:true,
                minlength:50,
                  maxlength:600 
            }
        },
      });
    var detail=$('#giver_comment_text').val();

//$.post(The content of AJAX);
}
```

Comment: jQuery.validate attaches itself to the `onsubmit` event of the form. So validation is performed just before submitting. You will need to show your code to better understand the scenario.

Comment: +1 a sample would be great ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove the function from the `onClick` handler, and use a `submitHandler`. Read the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options), and here's the sample they provide there:

```
$(".selector").validate({   
  submitHandler: function(form) {
  // do other stuff for a valid form
  form.submit();    
  } 
})
```

So all you have to do is call `function()` inside the `submitHandler` after the form has been validated.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Where to place ('#add_text').validate({
        rules:{
                giver_comment_text:{
                        required:true,
                        minlength:50,
                  maxlength:600 
                }
        },
      });

Comment: `submitHandler` is one of the options to the `validate` function. Just look at the samples provided at the link.