# Form validate function plus onclick function

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-validate

I have a html form with one input type text and a submit button. Now onclick with the submit button I run an ajax call to a php function and to stuff to my DB and all works fine eccc. So now I got all that working I thought I needed simply to put a form validation to check no one is passing the input type text empty.
I downloaded this:

http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Now if I comment my onclick function and just run $(#formid).validate(); it reads my required tags and works perfectly. But if I keep both the validate funnction and the onclick function the validate one stops working (while onclick works as clockwork). Is it not possible to have both? How can I work around it?

Thanks as always,
James

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can JQuery validate() be executed before onClick="functionname()";](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672193/how-can-jquery-validate-be-executed-before-onclick-functionname)

Comment: Show your code.  With jQuery, you wouldn't also use inline JavaScript.  With jQuery Validate, you don't _need_ any kind of `click` handler at all.  Again, show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `submitHandler:` option to the `validate()` method to provide your AJAX submission function.

This example is in the [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/):

```
$(".selector").validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    $(form).ajaxSubmit();
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks that was it, don't know why I didn't find that duplicate question. Sorry.